# UPDATE a table from the SELECT of another one

Tags: sqlite, sql-update

- I have a first table `articles` where some data are missing.
- In the table `articles_tmp` I have a part of the missing data.
- So I want to UPATE `articles.path WHERE path IS NULL` with the data in `articles_tmp.path WHERE path IS NOT NULL`.

With **SQLite**, this doesn't works :

```
UPDATE articles 
SET path = (
      SELECT  at.path
      FROM articles_tmp AS at, articles AS a
      WHERE at.article_id = a.id AND a.path IS NULL AND NOT at.path IS NULL
)
WHERE path IS NULL
```

With MS Access, this works fine :

```
UPDATE  articles
    INNER JOIN  articles_tmp 
    ON  articles.id = articles_tmp.id 
SET  articles.path = articles_tmp.path
WHERE  articles.path IS NULL  AND  articles_tmp.path IS NOT NULL
```

Can someone help ?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Everywhere _articles.path WHERE path IS NULL_ I get the same data which... (witch) is the first data from _articles_tmp.path_ that maches the request.

Comment: So, it updates at the good place with a wrong data, the same everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the SQL Server syntax I provided did not work, here is the solution I came up with.  Just a slight modification of your original query, but with my "correlation" suggestion added.  Here is an SQL fiddle for it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/34589/7

Here is the code:

```
UPDATE articles
SET path = (SELECT path FROM articles_tmp AS t WHERE t.id = articles.id)
WHERE path IS NULL;
```

Comment: I can't figure out a database system is usefull if we can not do this kind of basic operations. But I heard nice comments about SQLite...

Comment: Ok, so I guess that syntax won't work with SQLite.  The reason you are having the issue you get with your original query is because the subquery (inside parenthesis) isn't correlated to your outer query, so it just sets the data = the first row of your subquery.  If you add some criteria to your subquery, such as giving your outer articles table a reference name, like "original" or something, and then make sure that the `articles_tmp.id` = `original.id`, and you wouldn't even need the `articles` table in your subquery.

Comment: hum... I'm not sure. How would you write it ?

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect the changes I mentioned.

Comment: I saw your fiddle that you posted (not sure where the comment went), but it looked like you only had 'path' data for id=1 for both `articles` and `articles_tmp`.  The id=2 and id=3 had NULL values for both tables, so it wouldn't have updated anything.

Comment: Still a probleme if I just change the data. [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/5b402/2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/5b402/2)

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me.  You don't have any 'path' data in your `articles_tmp` for id=2 and id=3.  See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/2f4fb/1

Comment: **You're right, it works!** I mistaken with the NULL, NULL data in my sqlfiddle.com. And it also works on my local like this: `UPDATE articles SET path = (  SELECT path FROM articles_tmp WHERE article_id = articles.id  AND NOT path IS NULL  ) WHERE path IS NULL;` I use _articles.id_ and _articles_tmp.article_id_. Thanks. (The below still works too on my local.)

Answer (score 0):

That works (very correlated, probably too much) :

```
UPDATE articles
SET path = (
        SELECT at.path
        FROM articles_tmp AS at
        WHERE at.article_id=articles.id 
    )
WHERE EXISTS  (
        SELECT *
        FROM articles_tmp AS at
        WHERE at.article_id=articles.id AND articles.path IS NULL AND NOT at.path=''
    )
```

Comment: That works on my local but not on sqlfiddle.com whitch based on SQL.js